# WPF Dependency Property On Change Update Control

Tags: c#, wpf, dependencies, dependency-properties

I am currently trying to get a view to update when a dependency value changes.

I have copied the code from the view into it's parent and didn't use the dependency and it worked fine.  I believe my issue is with how I am creating the DependencyProperty.

```
public partial class CULabelConfigControl : UserControl {

    private CreditUnion CU { get; set; }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CUProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "CU",
        typeof(CreditUnion),
        typeof(CULabelConfigControl),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null)
    );
```

I currently receive an Error at run time:

```
"A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'CU' property of type 'CULabelConfigControl'. 
 A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject."
```

Any point in the right direction would be helpful.  And let me know if I need to share any other details.

Comment: That declaration is broken for multiple reasons. Please first read [Custom Dependency Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/custom-dependency-properties). In addition to what is explained there, you don't need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged for dependency properties. They provide their own change notification mechanism.

Comment: Thanks, I will trim the INotifyPropertyChanged out, I was just trying anything to get it to work at that point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should look like this:

```
public partial class CULabelConfigControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CUProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(CU),
            typeof(CreditUnion),
            typeof(CULabelConfigControl));

    public CreditUnion CU
    {
        get { return (CreditUnion)GetValue(CUProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CUProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

In the XAML of your UserControl, you would bind to this property by specifying the UserControl as RelativeSource, e.g.

```
<Label Content="{Binding CU, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
```

---

If you need to get notified in the UserControl class whenever the property value changes, you should register a PropertyChangedCallback:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty CUProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(CU),
        typeof(CreditUnion),
        typeof(CULabelConfigControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(CUPropertyChanged));

private static void CUPropertyChanged(
    DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var control = (CULabelConfigControl)obj;

    // react on value change here
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I updated the code for a missmatch of type.  'CurrentReading' should be 'CU' sorry.

Comment: This solved the runtime error, but for some reason doesn't trigger the view to change when the dependency object changes.

Comment: You should have a RelativeSource Binding to the CU property somewhere in the XAML of CULabelConfigControl. See the edit.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to add my XAML to your answer.  I was trying to add it to my question for reference.

Comment: That worked perfectly.  I did need the DependencyPropertyChangedEvent.  Thank you for all your help.